# How to import my own class into an Xcode 7 playground?

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7, swift-playground

I know this question was asked before, but I didn't find an answer in relation to Xcode 7 and Swift 2. Many answers are just ambiguous, incorrect or outdated.

Is there a clear way to import a single class or a set of classes to a playground?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Playground go to menu

> View / Navigators / Show Project Navigator

and copy your class files into the `Sources` folder.

Your classes have to be marked `public` like this:

```
public class MyPlayGround {
    public class func sayHello() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}
```

The Playground will then have access to the classes:

```
MyPlayGround.sayHello()
```

Comment: Is there a way to link, not just copy/paste files?

Comment: Not that I know of, because Playgrounds are Sandboxed and this "Sources" folder is actually an alias for an autogenerated /var folder unique to each Playground.