# Playground Import: No Such Module 'Foo'

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7, swift-playground

I've diligently followed the Apple instructions to import a custom module into a playground, including the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24049021/1286639).  And yet I get:

> Playground execution failed: /var/folders/z3/kd0nj4ln1rgcpm8bdz7067wh0000gs/T/./lldb/1874/playground1.swift:7:8: error: no such module 'Foo'
>   import Foo

How can I recover to a working Playground import? [Edit: Note, two answers have produced detailed instructions to associate a playground with a framework; I have followed those instructions but no luck.  **The solution will need to involve reconfiguring something in Xcode; my installation is apparently broken**]

Detailed images of the error and attempts:
[image]

Here is another attempt, based on the answer of @EricD, showing the directory structure, no dice.
[image]

Comment: did you try to put it above your `var`?

Comment: Still not found.  (Apple examples show the `import` line anywhere in the Playground.)

Comment: Anybody?  Anybody at all?

Comment: I did have the same issue. After recreating the playground from scratch solved this issue. However, there are other causes of this issue like "no such module": for example, if a playground contains a `Sources` folder whose sources import a custom module, this module will not be found. I didn't find a solution so far.

Comment: Well **Foo.h** is Objective-C if you mean **FooX** that would perfectly be valid. but `.h` file should be use with **header-bridge.h** if you want to implement it into swift. now even when you create foo in swift you can declare as following as well `var fooVariable = foo()`

Comment: Any solution yet? I hit a wall trying to import GPUImage in an iOS XCPlayground

Comment: @Cedric, see my answer below.

Comment: @GoZoner I tried it, but for me it was already set to Unique. Found the solution nevertheless. I had to build the framework with a scheme for an iOS simulator device (any in the list), not for "Generic iOS Device".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The solution**, from Apple Support, was to adjust my Xcode Preferences.  On Locations :: Advanced my configuration was 'Legacy'.  By changing to 'Unique', and undoing any paths I'd attempted to insert, Playgrounds can **now** import frameworks.

Comment: This worked for me I also had to close and reopen the project **Swift4.1  Xcode 9.3**

Comment: This did not work for me with macOS playgrounds. The workaround in my answer  is still the only way I've been able to get around this issue (which is still present in Xcode 10.1)

Answer (score 54):

For some of those that none of the above solutions work (and that Xcode build path setting was already set to `Unique`), I've found a solution.

The framework must be built with a scheme for an iOS simulator device (any in the list) and NOT a `Generic iOS Device`, as Playgrounds do not support it. This one worked for me :

[image: Working scheme]

Comment: The pod must be compile at least once before using it in playground. so if you've just install the pod, and haven't launch your app, then yes, you need to build it manually!

Comment: This is fantastic :) Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, @Cedric. That did the trick for me (Xcode 8.1, swift 3)

Comment: All devices won't work, you must select a 64-bit one (iPhone 5 will not work whereas iPhone 5s will)

Comment: @JeromeDiaz Thanks - useful!

Comment: doh! obvious but still helpful

Comment: Wow. This is such an absurd detail... thanks for sharing!

Comment: That was it!  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Apple. Another day wasted.

Comment: I'm using an iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator on the latest OS, still no dice...

Answer (score 14):

Here's how I proceed for OS X with Xcode 7.1:

- Create new project: OS X Cocoa Framework, Swift. For this example I named it "TestPlaygroundFMK".
- Create a new Swift file.
- Add a class to the file. *The code has to be public.* I made this for our example:

```
import Foundation

public class Talk {
    public class func sayHello() {
        print("Hello from framework!")
    }
}
```

- Build the project now.
- In the menu bar, click on File > Save As Workspace.
- Create a new Playground and save it inside the project folder next to the Swift files.

[image]

The Playground must *not* have the same name as the project.

- Build the project again.
- Import your framework in the Playground and use it:

```
import TestPlaygroundFMK

Talk.sayHello()
```

[image]

Comment: What is the 'project folder'?  (Next to 'Info.plist' or next to 'build').  After creating a new playground you then drag it into the workspace?

Comment: Sorry, I've already tried three possibilities and all have failed.  Where do you save the workspace and playground relative to the location of TestPlaygroundFMK.xcodeproj?

Comment: [Here's a Zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jpelpn0dyq826dm/TestPlaygroundFMK.zip?dl=0) of my version if you want to compare.

Comment: Okay.  I updated my answer with an attempt following your instructions.  Then, I downloaded your zip, opened the workspace, built the framework and changed to the playground.  Still the same problem!  Obviously my Xcode installation is fouled.

Answer (score 8):

I had my playground working fine but found that when I quit Xcode and re-opened it, I would get an error like this:

> error:
>   /var/folders/ft/bmk8wh6s5ms4my2pxhn3qbp40000gn/T/playground1-9216e0..swift:3:8:
>   error: no such module 'Playground_Sources' import Playground_Sources

... where "Playground" is the name of my playground file.

The solution to this (in Xcode 9.0) is to:

- click any playground file in your workspace
- show the Utilities panel (`opt`-`cmd`-`0`)
- under "Playground Settings" change the "Platform" to anything else then set it back.

In my case, it's set to `macOS`.  I changed it to `iOS` then back to `macOS` (no recompilation necessary) and it started to work fine... that is until I close Xcode and open it again.

This is the only solution I found to work with **macOS playgrounds**.  This bug still exists in Xcode 9.3.

Comment: Xcode 9.3 is working for me this solution, for iOS playgrounds.

Comment: This solution worked for me on Xcode 11.3.1 for an iOS playground

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure i had the exact problem as the original question - but given the mix and age of solutions and the lack of this one that DID work for me, i thought I'd share.

In Xcode 11+ (tested this on 12.2), i'd often have Playgrounds fail to run givn the "No Such Module" error when it included a framework that is a part of the workspace.

The solution for me was in the "File Inspector" for the Playground, and the "Build Active Scheme" option:

[image: Build Active Scheme]

This ensures the project was being built appropriately for the target, and now my annoying compile issues are gone!

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a workspace as below:

   - Choose File > New > Workspace
   - Enter the workspace name, and specify its location in your file system
   - Click Save
2. Now, Create a Cocoa framework with swift file which have your class

   - Choose File > New > Project
   - Select Cocoa framework > Next
   - Enter Product Name and Language > Next
   - Before clicking create, in 'Add to:' and 'Group' list choose 'Your workspace name' as shown [image: Add to workspace]
   - Framework is added to your workspace
3. Create swift file in your framework

   - In Xcode right click on the folder where you want to add swift file and select new file...
   - Select swift > Next > Name your file > Create
4. Select your framework in Xcode -> Build your framework
5. Create playground -> Playground should also be part of your workspace, if not drag it to your workspace, it'll be added automatically.

   - Right click in Xcode's files section  > New file... > Playground
   - import
   - Call your method

Note: If you just wanted to add classes instead of framework to your playground check the link [How to import my own class into an Xcode 7 playground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722275/how-to-import-my-own-class-into-an-xcode-7-playground?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description; unfortunately, I'm left with the same problem: `Playground execution failed: /var/folders/z3/kd0nj4ln1rgcpm8bdz7067wh0000gs/T/./lldb/27542/playground126.swift:7:8: error: no such module 'Again'
import Again`

Comment: [Here is example zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qvqivdsum9384c7/CustomFramework.zip?dl=0) Download example and open Custom framework workspace. Build TestFramework and t target then run playground.

Comment: Hi @AnniS I opened your dropbox project (actually, the workspace) in Xcode 7.1.1. The console just outputs: Playground execution failed: /var/folders/jl/yprcnzkd53g0d3nsmts8p6r40000gn/T/./lldb/39159/playground80.swift:7:8: error: no such module 'TestFramework'
import TestFramework
       ^
/var/folders/jl/yprcnzkd53g0d3nsmts8p6r40000gn/T/./lldb/39159/playground80.swift:11:8: error: no such module 't'
import t

Comment: @LS.Shanghai Just build the TestFramework before running playground.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution that worked for me:**

1. Setup your workspace and project/framework.
2. Delete derived data ([How to remove derived data?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42760524/9188735))
3. DO NOT BUILD YOUR PROJECT YET
4. Create playground file with different name then your project/target/framework name under folder with either Swift files or where .xcodeproj is located (does not matter which one you chose)
5. Build your project under required platform (if playground is for macOS, then build project with macOS target, etc.)
6. When build finishes try adding some code to your playground and run it.

**P.S**. you might need to restart Xcode before 6th step.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a stretch to say that Xcode is somewhat of a blackbox.  I make no claim that this will work for anyone else, but for me, after having the same issue after creating a new playground and a new framework target, and all the other proposed solutions, what finally worked was deleting the workspace file and (in my case) regenerating it with cocoapods.

I have no idea why this worked.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Build the framework with release ,this worked for me. (Xcode 10.1, swift 4.2)

Answer (score 0):

Insert a var at the first line and re run

```
var str = ""
```