# Xcode "Playground execution failed: error: Couldn't lookup symbols"

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8, swift-playground

I'm trying to set up a playground for a Swift framework I'm working on. I've followed the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33451726/6348578) but trying to access members of the framework stops playground execution and throws:

```
Playground execution failed: error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
__symbol1...
__symbol2...
...
```

I've made sure that the members are public. I can import the module itself and Xcode even shows code completion for the members, but the playground itself won't run because of the error.

Comment: I tried putting together a sample and don't seem to be getting the error anymore. I'll update my question if the issue returns.