# How to install Google Maps for Swift Playgrounds?

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, swift-playground

Hi so im trying to use the GoogleMaps SDK for a Swift Playground, but anything I look up doesn't show me how to install it. I tried following the tutorial for simple iOS projects (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) but this what I get.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33451726/2227743

Comment: @Moritz I understand that id have to make a different project and import it into this playground, but that seems kind of round about